# 'adb connect' sometimes adds an extra :4321 suffix

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

While debugging on my ADT-1 unit, I often connect via the following command

```
adb connect 192.168.1.x:4321
```

and this usually works as expected. I noticed that, in some occasions, **the connection fails** because the `adb connect` command adds an extra port suffix to the original address:

```
unable to connect to 192.168.1.7:4321:4321 // see the extra :4321?
```

Some additional info:

1. Yes, the 4321 is mandatory for ADT-1 devices.
2. Restarting the adb service does not do anything useful.
3. Restarting the IDE (IDEA / Studio) doesn't seem to do the trick.

Does anyone know why this happens? Can it be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that rebooting the tcpip server on the device fixes this. Steps to do this:

- Plug the device in to a computer via USB
- Run 'adb usb' to connect to the device via USB
- Run 'adb tcpip 4321' to restart the tcpip server on port 4321
- Unplug the device
- Run 'adb connect 192.168.1.x:4321' and it should now connect successfully.

Comment: How do you connect ADT-1 to a computer with USB??

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue occurs when the **IP assigned to ADT-1 changes**.

`adb connect` cannot communicate with that address (since it has changed), hence it throws that misleading error.

Comment: This is not the reason its happening to me.  Worked yesterday but not today and the device has the same IP.

Comment: What is the new port number for this device?

Comment: @dextor That seems intuitive.  Yet, it is not a solution.